# How did Crowley get the syringe?

Tags: supernatural

In the Supernatural episode "[Heaven Can't Wait](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3112656/)" (S09E06) Crowley seems to have nicked one of Sam's syringes and is seen injecting himself. Since he seems well-confined to the Demon Trap, *how did he get it?*

Even if he just snatched it from the table while Sam and Kevin were getting the translation (@ approx the 36:30 mark) it seems there wasn't much time (about 3 seconds) to grab it, pull a hypo's-worth of Kevin's blood from the bowl, and hide it. Especially since the bowl was only one hypo's-worth to begin with, and Sam is seen dumping a significant amount of blood out of the bowl (@ approx 39:20) and washing it before he notices (remembers?) the bag of syringes. It certainly looked like a good amount of blood in the syringe (@ approx 39:43). It's also a different syringe. At the table Sam grabs the first syringe on the left (@ approx 25:59) but the missing syringe later is the second from the right. Granted, this *could* be a continuity error, but *maybe not*.

I'm guessing he nicked it from the table and somehow filled it with Kevin's blood, but it doesn't seem to fit the facts above. Maybe someone else saw or figured out something I missed.

"Seems like you answered your own question" comments are not that helpful in this instance since the blood itself did not seem to go missing. And what else would he be injecting? I hope this is not too much info (including times even) for the question, I just wanted to show I did my due diligence before asking.

Comment: I like badges, but getting The Tumbleweed felt more like a kick in the nuts than an honor. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sam grabs a syringe, but then puts it back when Crowley says he wants Kevin's blood.  Sam is about to put them away when Kevin grabs one - the second from the right.

Sam takes the syringe from Kevin, pours *most* of the blood into the bowl, and puts both the bowl and the syringe (which looks like it still contains at least a small amount of blood) on the table in front of Crowley.  It's visible throughout that first scene but I don't recall seeing a clear shot of it on the table in the following one that's intercut with Cas's confrontation with the angel medic.

When he's done with the call, Crowley reaches out and slowly pushes the bowl away from himself towards Sam with that "I'm kind of screwed" look, and drags his hand back across the table to his lap, palm down.  It looks like that's when he grabs the syringe, using his reaction to the call with Abaddon to cover it.  Sneaky!

The amount of blood in the syringe strains credibility a bit, and it's possible that he then grabs more blood from the bowl with it when their backs are turned, but I don't know that it's completely necessary for the story to work, and anyway, how 'pure' can blood be that's been used for a demonic phone call?

Comment: Some of this doesn't make sense, but the needle placement is valid. I missed that. I'm inclined to accept and just notch the rest up to "meh." Supernatural has pretty good continuity, but nobody's perfect...